# Cant add menu links to container

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, slider

I have a logo and image slider in a container so that they are side by side at all times but Im trying to add 3 Menu links horizontally under the Logo but I cant seem to do it, they keep going above the image slider which jams that downwards. Any suggestions on what to do?

Heres the jsfiddle : jsfiddle.net/gZDVL/17/

Answer (score 6):

Conceptually, it seems you want two columns. Why not make your HTML represent that?

```
<div>
    <!-- logo and links here -->
</div>
<div>
    <!-- slider here -->
</div>
```

Float those divs, and you're good.

Comment: the problem with that fiddle is the links are vertical i need them to be horizontal and now the image slider has become jumbled, the left slider button is now over the slider and the right slider button is underneath. About the code you've pasted above, i apoligise for my noobness but im not sure about how to float them properly do you think you could in the jsfiddle ? : http://jsfiddle.net/gZDVL/17/

Comment: No. (Plus some more characters)

Comment: how come? i tried what you said with the div tags and that does not work, i dont know how to do this

Comment: Because I'm not going to write your code for you. Your links are not horizontal in the code you gave me. As for the slider buttons, you'll have to play with the width of the slider - I set it to 100%, but something like 80% (with each button being 10%) might be more preferable. Hope this helps.